# Stuck at using PAT (Personal Access Token) in GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I have one GitHub account.

I have one private organization. And a couple of private repositories.

I want to define an action for my private repository, in my private organization.

`private_org\private_rpo`

And I can checkout my `private_repo` using `${{ github.token }}` and `action/checkout@2`.

However, I'm stuck at checking out my other repo in this repo's action.

Here's my code:

```
      - name: Get private_org/private_repo using actions/checkout@v2
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: private_org/private_repo
          token: ${{ github.token }}
          path: private_org/private_repo
          
      - name: Get private_org/private_repo_2 using actions/checkout@v2
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: private_org/private_repo_2
          token: ${{ github.pat }}
          path: private_org/private_repo_2
```

I have created a PAT in my accounts (developer settings), and I have defined `pat` as a secret in `private_org/private_repo`.

However, `action/checkout@2` complains that:

> Run actions/checkout@v2
> Error: Input required and not supplied: token

How should I solve this? Where should I define my `pat` secrect? How can I checkout my other private repository in this private repository's action?

Comment: we can also use `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` as a safer alternative for `${{ github.token }}` since the former is created before a job and destructs after it. check this https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#permissions-for-the-github_token

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem occured because you don't use `secrets` that way on github actions.

- You used `${{ github.pat }}` which is reserved to github variables in github context ([you can find more informations about the github context here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#contexts)).
- You should use `${{ secrets.pat }}` to manage your `PAT` secret in your workflow ([you can find more informations about this nomenclature here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets)).

**Here is the part to update:**

```
      - name: Get private_org/private_repo_2 using actions/checkout@v2
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: private_org/private_repo_2
          token: ${{ secrets.pat }} # use "secrets." instead of "github."
          path: private_org/private_repo_2
```